# How to duplicate a cross tab

Tags: jasper-reports

Background: Jaspersoft Studio 6.2

How to duplicate a crosstab properly? E.g. I have this report, two crosstabs. The second one is created by simply copy and paste from the first one.

[image]

But when preview:

[image]

The second one shows nulls.

The source:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="test" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="6fcf63da-959b-4272-90d7-f36888d89689">
        <style name="Crosstab_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
        </style>
        <style name="Crosstab_CG" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
        </style>
        <style name="Crosstab_CT" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#005FB3">
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
        </style>
        <style name="Crosstab_CD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
        </style>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[select 'a' as item,  'c1' as cat, 10 as value
    union all select 'a' as item,  'c2' as cat, 10 as value
    union all select 'b' as item,  'c1' as cat, 10 as value
    union all select 'b' as item,  'c2' as cat, 10 as value]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="item" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="cat" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="value" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <title>
            <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
        </title>
        <summary>
            <band height="220" splitType="Stretch">
                <crosstab>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="560" height="90" uuid="c1a01692-6e33-4959-ba10-063d690144f5">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <rowGroup name="item1" width="60" totalPosition="End">
                        <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                            <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{item}]]></bucketExpression>
                        </bucket>
                        <crosstabRowHeader>
                            <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                                <textField>
                                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="5cc90958-7226-4ca2-b33d-bc187fd23381"/>
                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{item1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                            </cellContents>
                        </crosstabRowHeader>
                        <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                            <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                                <staticText>
                                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="60b92423-2107-47c3-a6c4-eb7644dc9333"/>
                                    <text><![CDATA[Total item1]]></text>
                                </staticText>
                            </cellContents>
                        </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                    </rowGroup>
                    <columnGroup name="cat1" height="20" totalPosition="End">
                        <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                            <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{cat}]]></bucketExpression>
                        </bucket>
                        <crosstabColumnHeader>
                            <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                                <textField>
                                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="6ea9bfbc-51e4-4c0b-9249-04dc3e129caa"/>
                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{cat1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                            </cellContents>
                        </crosstabColumnHeader>
                        <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                            <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                                <staticText>
                                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="bdb25d96-760e-46a8-9329-d6383f796cc6"/>
                                    <text><![CDATA[Total cat1]]></text>
                                </staticText>
                            </cellContents>
                        </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                    </columnGroup>
                    <measure name="value_MEASURE1" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Count">
                        <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}]]></measureExpression>
                    </measure>
                    <crosstabCell width="60" height="20">
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CD">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="ae67a592-dc64-4cf8-a9ad-565fe05afe91"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{value_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabCell>
                    <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" columnTotalGroup="cat1">
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="ba1cbf16-b568-4e00-b6b6-4b8bae8af5ca"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{value_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabCell>
                    <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="item1">
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="7aa6a6a5-f976-4aad-915b-745598bc6cb5"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{value_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabCell>
                    <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="item1" columnTotalGroup="cat1">
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="1c70e81c-937a-4458-8af7-dc84a4d7337f"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{value_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabCell>
                </crosstab>
                <crosstab>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="130" width="560" height="90" uuid="bc6bf01c-59d7-45d5-95e1-4e2ed10eb4d4">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <rowGroup name="item1" width="60" totalPosition="End">
                        <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                            <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{item}]]></bucketExpression>
                        </bucket>
                        <crosstabRowHeader>
                            <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                                <textField>
                                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="2eaed006-01ff-42e6-8094-064f4d64d95f"/>
                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{item1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                            </cellContents>
                        </crosstabRowHeader>
                        <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                            <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                                <staticText>
                                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="e6fa60f1-e100-4da9-ae3c-9857a7c7e4f4"/>
                                    <text><![CDATA[Total item1]]></text>
                                </staticText>
                            </cellContents>
                        </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                    </rowGroup>
                    <columnGroup name="cat1" height="20" totalPosition="End">
                        <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                            <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{cat}]]></bucketExpression>
                        </bucket>
                        <crosstabColumnHeader>
                            <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                                <textField>
                                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="3159af5f-9ee9-42c0-afba-eb5d3a6146d9"/>
                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{cat1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                            </cellContents>
                        </crosstabColumnHeader>
                        <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                            <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                                <staticText>
                                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="0fe74d0c-15ea-4641-aeb2-f8fb4e4e3474"/>
                                    <text><![CDATA[Total cat1]]></text>
                                </staticText>
                            </cellContents>
                        </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                    </columnGroup>
                    <measure name="value_MEASURE1" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Count">
                        <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}]]></measureExpression>
                    </measure>
                    <crosstabCell width="60" height="20">
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CD">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="5a6a9ee0-2702-4de7-91b4-f1688f8fed40"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{value_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabCell>
                    <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" columnTotalGroup="cat1">
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="6b40b142-41bd-467f-9ce7-01d02d534cd9"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{value_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabCell>
                    <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="item1">
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="5f1889f1-b25f-4d12-8fc9-6fe10245ff2a"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{value_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabCell>
                    <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="item1" columnTotalGroup="cat1">
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="02c95509-6115-4147-824e-d0e58445eec2"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{value_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabCell>
                </crosstab>
            </band>
        </summary>
    </jasperReport>
```

How can I properly duplicate a crosstab?

Comment: Try to duplicate datasource (with another name)

Comment: That works, thanks. But I am not sure this is a bug or lack of feature because it works  if I just manually recreate the second tab (instead of copy and paste) using the same data source.

Comment: I think it is a bug of JSS. I faced the similar issue

Comment: I think this is not a bug. The iterator for the dataset will be at the end of the set after the first crosstab. Since there is no rewinding, the second crosstab will not be filled because the iterator is already at the end of the data set. Especially because both crosstabs are an element of the Summary band.

Comment: @tobi6 this may be the reason. But not everyone is a Java developer and doesn't care about how it internally works. Compared with many other tools, this really is a missing feature (along with many other features). But my complaint stops when thinking of it's free...